# When is the first commercial Rocket Lab launch occurring out of Mahia Peninsula, New Zealand?

Tags: launch-site, spaceflight-firsts, rocketlab

Rocket Lab announced the [new launch site](http://www.stuff.co.nz/business/industries/75361113/rocket-lab-begins-work-on-electron-rocket-launch-site-in-mahia) at Mahia last year. Which is due for completion soon. According to their [booking system](http://book.rocketlabusa.com/) commercial launches will happen in quarter 4 of 2016.

Do we know the exact date of the first commercial launch? I.e. excluding any test launches.

Answer (score 2):

We currently do not know the first date of the first commercial launch, other than that they have fast tracked their testing program.

*#StillTesting*, their 2nd test launch, [however does include a number of commercial payloads onboard, including 2 Dove satellites for Planet, and 2 Lemur-2 satellites from Spire](https://www.nbr.co.nz/article/rocket-labs-second-test-launch-carry-weather-mapping-satellites-ck-p-208114), **and launched successfully on 21 January 2018**.

Whether this qualifies as a commercial launch is up to you — future launches may be "all commercial" but will absolutely include testing elements, as RocketLab models its agile methodology after bigger newspace companies such as SpaceX. So they will always be testing. They'll just be making money doing it :)

Comment: add something about Humanity Star? ([questions](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/humanitystar) tagged with `humanitystar`)